# Compare fields in a document Using MongoDB Compass

Tags: mongodb, filter, compass

I have a MongoDB schema with documents that contain 2 date fields.
I need to filter for only documents where the named date fields don't match using Compass.

Example:
created_date is 10/04/2023
modified_date is 09/24/2023

Filter records where created_date is not equal to the modified_date

I can filter for a known string but am not able to determine the proper method for comparing one array field to another within the same document record.

Comment: Yes, actually it does and I hate that.  Thanks Ray

{filter1: 'testtextfilter', $where : "this.createDate != this.modifiedDate"}